# Is there behavior changes for sudo-1.8.6p3-15.x86_64 (RHEL6.6) as compared to sudo-1.6.9p17-6?

Tags: linux, bash, sudo, rhel6

We found that there is a behavioural changes in sudo-1.8.6p3-15.x86_64 (RHEL6.6) as compared to sudo-1.6.9p17-6 (RHEL 5.8)
Detailed level explanation is mentioned below.

It has been observed if a script called through “sudo”, and if Ctrl+C (SIGINT) sent to the foreground process, then the control returns to the parent process instead of terminal.

Steps to Reproduce:

We have executed below 2 scripts on RHEL5 and RHEL6.6 machine.
a). parent.sh (Parent)
b). child.sh (Child)

1st script parent.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo /root/child.sh
echo "Parent Process"
```

2nd script child.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello"
sleep 90
```

Expected results:

Behaviour of this in RHEL5 (with sudo 1.6.9)
Whenever we send SIGINT to the parent, the child as well as parent got killed and control returns to the terminal.

```
    # sh parent.sh 
    hello
    ------> Ctrl+C pressed here
                                    ---> Both parent and child got killed.
parent.sh(14867) -> child.sh(14869) -> sleep(14870)
```

Actual results:

In RHEL 6.6 (with sudo-1.8.6p3), if SIGINT sent to efg.sh as only child process is getting killed and afterwards parent continues execution until it's graceful exit or again sending SIGINT by user.

```
    # sh parent.sh 
    hello
    --------> Ctrl+C pressed here
    Parent Process  --> Parent still exist, but child killed
    -------> Ctrl+C pressed here
parent.sh(14867) -> sudo(14868) -> child.sh(14869) -> sleep(14870)
```

Here, extra sudo process is generated in new sudo package but older package it is not created.

Comment: This might be a better question at unix.stackexchange.com